# Convert minutes to HH:MM ReportViewer

Tags: c#, time, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a report where I need to sum the duration values.
By the moment I have the duration and the total duration, in minutes.
[image]

As you can see in "Duração Tarefa" column, I get the first values liek HH:MM, and the Total in Minutes.

What I need:
How can I convert that value (1935) to a HH:MM format?

Comment: The first question... what is the value 1935? a random int? a ticks since?

Comment: @PaulZahra It appears that 1935 is the number of minutes of the previous two records: ((8 hours * 60) + 20) + ((23 hours * 60) + 55) = 1935.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest using `DateTime.AddMinutes()`, but that limits you to the 24 hour day.

The below should work by doing some simple division:

```
    private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:{1}", 
                            GetHours(1935),
                            GetRemainderMinutes(1935)));
    }

    private int GetHours(int minutes)
    {
        // Get how many hours are contained in the total minutes
        return minutes / 60;
    }
    private object GetRemainderMinutes(int minutes)
    {
        // Get the remaining amount that couldn't be divided into hours.
        return minutes % 60;
    }
```

Comment: Use the same logic to derive your data in RDLC. Thanks @JoelC for the hint

Answer (score 3):

Here is my formula for the field based on the suggestion by JoelC

=Format(Floor(Fields!TotalMins.Value / 60), "#0") & "h:" & Format(Fields!TotalMins.Value mod 60, "00") & "m"

Floor is needed so that 5.6 does not give you 6 hours. The other formatting is there only for display purposes.